# What is the most secure way to encrypt a file with sensitive data?

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, gnupg

Can anyone recommend me a way to encode files of sensitive data so that no one can crack them? I will be the only who knows the password.

I am thinking of using GPG but I know next to nothing about security. Any suggestions which algorithm from GPG to use for encryption?

Thanks, Boda Cydo.

Comment: This clearly belongs on superuser.

Answer (score 2):

Put your data into a Thumb/USB drive, and use [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/)

Answer (score 2):

GPG is fine.  AES is a good choice as an algorithm, and since you are encrypting them only for your own use, symmetric encryption is fine:

```
gpg --symmetric --cipher-algo AES < infile > outfile
```

It will prompt you for a passphrase.  To decrypt:

```
gpg < infile > outfile
```